# NodeJS "crypto" hash seems to produce different output than Crypto-JS javascript library

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, sha, sha256

I am using NodeJS's bundled [`crypto`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) module for SHA256 hashing on the server-side.
On the client-side, I am using a javascript library called [`Crypto-JS`](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-2).

I am using SHA256 hashes for a login system that uses classical nonce-based authentication. However, my server-side and client-side hash-digests don't match up even when the hash-messages are the same (I have checked this). Even the length of the hash-digests are different.

This is a snippet of my client-side implementation:

```
var password_hash = CryptoJS.SHA256( token.nonce /*this is the server's nonce*/ + cnonce + password ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

This is a snippet of my server-side implementation:

```
var sha256 = CRYPTO.createHash("sha256");
sha256.update(snonce+cnonce+password, "utf-8");
var hash = sha256.digest("base64");
```

This is some sample data:

```
client-digest: d30ab96e65d09543d7b97d7cad6b6cf65f852f5dd62c256595a7540c3597eec4
server-digest: vZaCi0mCDufqFUwVO40CtKIW7GS4h+XUhTUWxVhu0HQ=

client-message: O1xxQAi2Y7RVHCgXoX8+AmWlftjSfsrA/yFxMaGCi38ZPWbUZBhkVDc5eadCHszzbcOdgdEZ6be+AZBsWst+Zw==b3f23812448e7e8876e35a291d633861713321fe15b18c71f0d54abb899005c9princeofnigeria
server-message: O1xxQAi2Y7RVHCgXoX8+AmWlftjSfsrA/yFxMaGCi38ZPWbUZBhkVDc5eadCHszzbcOdgdEZ6be+AZBsWst+Zw==b3f23812448e7e8876e35a291d633861713321fe15b18c71f0d54abb899005c9princeofnigeria
```

Does anyone know why the hashes are different? I thought that if it is the same protocol/algorithm, it will always produce the same hash.

Edit: Wow. I went to this [online hashing tool](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) and it produces yet another digest for the same message:

```
4509a6d5028b217585adf41e7d49f0e7c1629c59c29ce98ef7fbb96c6f27502c
```

Edit Edit: On second thought, the reason for the online hashing tool being different is probably because it uses a `hex` encoding and I used `base64`

Comment: I get the same one as the online hashing tool.  Are you sure you aren't changing the encoding of the string between the client and server?  Maybe a serialization protocol or a change from ascii to utf or back?  Just one bit different will give a completely different hash.

Comment: @dhj I don't think the encoding changed anything. I converted all my nonces to base64 so everything is a string. I also console logged the hash-message on both the browser and server and compared them (the hash-message in the question is copy pasted from console output).

Comment: Well that server and client digest are definitely two different result encodings.  The client is in hex the server probably base64.  SHA256 will always return a 256 bit digest.

Comment: @dhj Oh yeah! The client-digest looks very much like a `hex` string. This is perplexing...I explicitly told it to output a base64 string with `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);`...I'll have to think of a workaround...

Comment: @dhj Found the problem! Thank you!

Comment: No problem!  Have a good weekend!  What did it turn out to be?

Comment: @dhj I made an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was indeed with encodings.

Look at the client-side implementation:

`var password_hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(message).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);`

The `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` parameter actually requires another component in the CryptoJS library that I did not include (stored in a js file: `enc-base64-min.js`). So, in the absence of a valid encoding type, it defaulted to `hex`.

Thanks @dhj for pointing out the encoding issue!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your client produces hex-encoded digest, while server uses base64 encoding.