# Hash value of same string is different in Android and Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, sha256

The hash values of the same string is different in Javascript and Android for SHA-256:

Javascript Code:

```
var hashedPassword = CryptoJS.SHA256(userPassword);
var passwordText = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Android Code:

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hashedPassword = messageDigest.digest(userPassword.getBytes());
String hashedPasswordText = Base64.encodeToString(hashedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
```

Output for String "beast":

In Javascript :

```
1bf417bd87162d5d77a5ce3259e81bdee9f8a0ef56bc0f12eadcd5805a94b708
```

In Android :

```
G/QXvYcWLV13pc4yWegb3un4oO9WvA8S6tzVgFqUtwg=
```

Comment: Your Javascript output string looks like Base16, not Base64. In fact, they're identical after transformation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000463/4810277)  `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` requires another component. And if it does not find it it defaults to HEX.